# In print settings I kept margins ... but it is working on first page only. I want margin top in second page too

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have the following method. From the backend I am getting margin top is 5... it is working fine in the first page of print but in second page margin top space is not coming.

```
initPrintSettings() {
this.commonService.getExistingPrintSettings().subscribe(res => {
  if (res["status"] && res["data"].length > 0) {
    this.printSettings = res["data"][0];
    console.log(this.printSettings);
    this.printSettings["margins"] =
      this.printSettings["margins"].split(",").join("cm ") + "cm";
  }
});
```

and I wrote the following print function

```
printWindow.document.write(
  '<body style="margin:' +
  this.printSettings["margins"] +
  '" onload="window.print();window.close();">'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want each page to have specific margins you can do the following:

```
printWindow.document.write(
    '<style>
        @page{ 
           size: auto;
           margin: ' + this.printSettings["margins"];+
        '}
    </style>
   <body onload="window.print();window.close();">'
);
```